# ASP.NET and AngularJS setup

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, angularjs

I'm following along with the demo for ASP.NET using AngularJS found here: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/3-644

I started by creating an empty C# ASP.Net project and these are my two files:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Card Demo</title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cardController.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="cardsListController">
    <div id="cardsList">
        <div ng-repeat="card in cards">
            Card {{card.id}}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

cardController.js:

```
var cardsListController = function ($scope) {
    $scope.cards = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];
};
```

But when I open up the index.html in chrome I get nothing, I have angular.min.js in the same folder and I've confirmed that it's showing up in the sources.

And finally in the inspect element I see this:

```
<body ng-controller="cardsListController" class="ng-scope">
    <div id="cardsList">
        <!-- ngRepeat: card in cards -->
    </div>


</body>
```

Any ideas on why it wouldn't be showing anything? Is there anymore setup to it that the demo video might have skipped over?

Thanks!

Comment: which version of angular are you using? the syntax you are using here isn't valid starting with angular 1.3.

Comment: @Claies Wow, I can't believe I've spent an hour looking at this and didn't event think to check Angular Versions (First time ever with Angular). I downloaded the newest, 1.4.5, are their minor things I should change or should I ditch this demo video and look for a newer one?

Comment: overall that's not a bad video if you are coming from a Microsoft background;  it should function fine if you make the changes as suggested in the duplicate I linked.

Comment: Thank you so much @Claies , That solved my issue!

Comment: good luck, I hope that you enjoy working with angular.  It has some phenomenal features.